# GITのリベースコマンドでコンフリクトが起きたときの表示について

Tags: git

git bashでリベースコマンドでmasterブランチの内容をfeatureブランチへマージすると
コンフリクトが起きたので対応してgit continueしたのですがまたコンフリクトの表示が
でます。「feature|REBASE 3/20」という表示もあるのですがこれはどういう意味を
指すのでしょうか。20/20になるまでコンフリクトの対応をし続けないといけないので
しょうか。

Comment: ログを質問文へコピー＆ペーストして頂くことは可能ですか？　隠すべき情報があれば伏せ字にして頂ければと思います。

Comment: あと、`git status`の結果も質問文に追加してもらえませんか？　gitで困ったときは、大体`git status`の結果にどうすれば良いかが表示されます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> feature|REBASE 3/20

という表示であるということはマージではなく`rebase`を行っていて、"git continue"というのは `git rebase --continue` のことだと解釈しました。

---

> 「feature|REBASE 3/20」という表示もあるのですがこれはどういう意味を指すのでしょうか。

オフィシャルな説明は見つけられなかったのですが、初回conflictが発生した箇所以降全部で`20`コミットがあり、今回処理しようとしているコミットはそのうち`3`つめである、という意味だと思います。

> 20/20になるまでコンフリクトの対応をし続けないといけないので
>   しょうか。

状況によりますが、最悪だとその通りです。最善の場合はそのconflictを解消すれば残りは何も対応せずにrebaseが成功します。

---

似たような状況を再現するスクリプトを作ってみました。

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir repo-conflict
pushd repo-conflict
git init
git commit --allow-empty -m init
echo 'hello, world' > hello.txt
git add hello.txt
git commit -m 'hello'
git checkout -b feature
for i in {1..5}; do
  echo $i >> hello.txt
  git commit -am "put $i"
done

git checkout master
echo 'goodbye, world' >> hello.txt
git commit -am 'goodbye'

git checkout feature
```

`repo-conflict` というディレクトリができるので、そこで

```
git rebase master
```

を実行すると

> (feature|REBASE 1/5)

の表記を伴ってconflictでrebaseが中断されます。

このときの `hello.txt` の内容は

```
hello, world
<<<<<<< HEAD
goodbye, world
=======
1
>>>>>>> put 1
```

となってますが、これを

```
hello, world
goodbye, world
1
```

と編集した後

```
git add hello.txt
git rebase --continue
```

すれば残りは手動対処不要でrebaseが完了します。

そうではなく

```
hello, world
1
goodbye, world
```

と編集した場合は後続のコミットは自動でマージできないのでconflictが発生し中断されます。